# Reading files from Drive folders with Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have mounted my Drive folders into Colab,

`from google.colab import drive drive.mount('/content/drive')`

but I can't get images inside that folders.

I want to iterate over the images inside that folder and resize them.
I tried `!ls /content/drive/path/to/folder`, it returns the names of the images, but when I make 'for' loop on that, after every iteration for every 'i' it returns string like this `'image.png pic.jpg\t more_contr499.jpg'` , i.e. the names of three images in one string, plus '\t'
So when I try to open image after every iteration it returns me an error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'image.png\t\t pic.jpg\t more_contr499.jpg'`

Comment: What did you try, and where did you get stuck? What error message did you encounter, if any?

Comment: @BobSmith I tried !ls /content/drive/path/to/folder, it returns the names of the images, but when I make 'for' loop on that, after every iteration it returns string like this  'image.png       pic.jpg\t  more_contr499.jpg' , i.e. the names of three images in one string, plus '\t'

Comment: So when I try to open image after every iteration it returns me an error:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'image.png\t\t pic.jpg\t more_contr499.jpg'